# Proper route to get controller action to work properly with passed argument - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 4.2.1
Ruby 2.1.5
```

In my routes.rb, I have:

```
get '/activate_test_set' =>  'test_sets#activate_test_set'
```

In test_sets_controller.rb, I have:

```
def activate_test_set test_set
  test_set.update_attribute(status: 'active')
  render test_sets_url
end
```

In my views/test_sets/index.html, I have:

```
<%= link_to "#{t('activate')}", activate_test_set_path(test_set) %>
```

When I'm in the view, if I click on the link, I get the following in the development error log:

```
Started GET "/activate_test_set.1" for ::1 at 2016-01-01 13:23:55 -0800
Processing by TestSetsController#activate_test_set as 
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
 app/controllers/test_sets_controller.rb:69:in `activate_test_set'
```

Whats' the proper routes.rb declaration to make this work correctly?

I also tried this in routes.rb:

```
get '/activate_test_set/:id' =>  'test_sets#activate_test_set'
```

and this is what I get:

```
Started GET "/activate_test_set.1" for ::1 at 2016-01-01 15:14:57 -0800
    SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/activate_test_set.1"):
```

## Solution:

Following some additional experimentation, here's how I solved this problem. Being a newbie, I am not sure this is the best solution, but here it goes:

```
match "activate_test_set/:id", :to => "test_sets#activate_test_set", :as => :activate_test_set, via: [:get]
```

Comment: as you can see from the error it doesn't direct you to the `activate_test_set` action but instead to the `pause_test_set` action. You can check out the right link shortcut methods by doing `rake routes` in the console.

Comment: change this `get '/activate_test_set' => 'test_sets#activate_test_set'` to `get '/activate_test_set/:id' => 'test_sets#activate_test_set'` and try i hope it will work

Comment: i copied the wrong part of the log file. I have both activate and play action. Please see the edits

Comment: Why do you have two versions of rails?

Comment: Typo: it's Ruby 2.1.5

Answer (score 0):

Try what Was suggested in the comments:

Changing `get '/active_test_set'...` to `get '/active_test_set/:id'`

Other way is to use normal params in which case you need to:

change the link tag to:
 `<%= link_to "#{t('activate')}", activate_test_set_path(id: test_set) %>`

Whichever route fix you choose, you don't need arguments in your controller action. Whenever your controller actions are used with routing, you don't need to have arguments for that action, but instead set parameters in the link tag(like showed in Fix 2) and the access them through `params` hash inside the controller action like so:

```
def activate_test_set
  test_set = TestSet.find(params[:id])
  test_set.update_attribute(status: 'active')
  render test_sets_url
end
```

EDIT: 
Use `rake routes` to see what the link method looks like for that action.

Comment: Not working either. My IDE (RubyMine) does not like the code either. When I removed the argument to the controller action, and added test_set = TestSet.find(params[:id]), it is now rejecting the line after that: test_set.update_attribute(status: 'active'). It thinks it needs two arguments and I am only passing one.

Comment: @Joseph `update_attribute(name, value)` - from [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute). so change it to `update_attribute('status', 'active')`

Comment: @Joseph did you look at the rake routes? Because your solution doesn't seem optimal. if you want a custom methods(like `active_test_set_path`) then user `:as`, but you can leave out `via: :get`, instead do `get "activate_test_set/:id", :to => "test_sets#activate_test_set", :as => :activate_test_set`

Answer (score 0):

In routes, you want to set a parameter

```
get '/activate_test_set/:id' =>  'test_sets#activate_test_set'
```

Then, when you link to it, it will add the test_set_id to the params hash and you'll be able to get it like so

```
def activate_test_set
  test_set = TestSet.find(params[:id])
  test_set.update_attribute(:status, 'active')

  ...

end
```

Also note, this error

```
Started GET "/activate_test_set.1" for ::1 at 2016-01-01 13:23:55 -0800
```

the .1 is the `format` (default is html).  When you sent the test_set as the param, it put the id of the test_set in the url as the format.  When you see this, it's is almost always not what you want.  It happens when you pass one too many parameters to the path method.

Comment: should have a comma `test_set.update_attribute(:status, 'active')`

Comment: Yes, I've fixed that. Now, it's telling me that it cannot find my route: activate_test_set_path

Comment: In console, try `rake routes` to see what methods you have.  They list will show all methods without "_path" or "_url" part of the method name.